# Implement Factory with generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, interface

I am abstracting out dependencies from contracts to decouple the dependencies

```
// Abstraction -- This can be published as contract where implementation needs to implement method. Most importantly 3rd party types are not present/tied to contract

public interface ISourceFactory {
   T GetSource<T>();
}


// Implementation which depends on specific source like 3rd party

public class SourceFactory {
    public T GetSource<T>()   //Unable to make this work
    {
        Type listType = typeof(T);
        if (listType == typeof(SomeBase))
        {
            return _connection.GetSource<T>();
        }
        if(listType == typeof(ExternalBase)){
            return _exconnection.GetSource<T>();
        }
        throw new Exception("Not supported");
    }

    private Connection _connection;
    private ExternalConnection _exconnection;
}

// 3rd party implementation
public class Connection {
    public T GetSource<T> where T : SomeBase
}

// 3rd party implementation
public class ExternalConnection {
    public T GetSource<T> where T : ExternalBase
}
```

However I am unable to make SourceFactory.GetSource to working as it cribs that T can't be used as generic parameter.

Can anyone suggest what's the generic approach for this problem?

Comment: `T` needs to be different things for each implementation, so no, you can't do this generically unless you pass `object` around and then cast it in each `GetSource`. Your `SourceFactory` here seems somewhat pointless, why don't you just call the `GetSource` on each instantiation? It seems like your trying to use a [abstract factory pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/abstract-factory-design-pattern) but this pattern relies on the fact that the results are in some way related, which in your instance, they're not

Comment: `public T GetSource<T>()  where T : class` ?

Comment: @Neil wouldn't work because each `T` in the instantiation has it's own contradicting constraint `where T : SomeBase` & `where T : ExternalBase`

Comment: As long as the 'base' classes declare T as class that shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: How can a base class declare `T`? It doesn't know what `T` is? @Neil

Comment: @Liam while I agree with you, How do I design this abstraction by keeping Dependency class out of contract?

Comment: If you removed the constraints on your instantiation(s) you could, but you can't have it both ways, you can't have strict incompatible constraints and a generic implementation you have to choose one or the other

Answer (score 1):

As said in the comments it's not possible per se, because connections must have something in common to be abstracted as generic. You are using 3. party components, but as you are trying to use them in one factory, I suppose you want to get same data from them. So I suggest to define an interface where you define the common part that you need:

```
public interface IConnection{
string GetConnectionString();
...
}
```

Than you wrap your 3d party connections:

```
public class SomebaseWrapper : IConnection{
public SomebaseWrapper(SomeBase b){
}
...
}
```

Than you ask for the wrapper in your factory:

```
public interface ISourceFactory {
   T GetSource<T>() where T is IConnection;
}
```

And finally you ask for SomebaseWrapper and implement it like this:

```
public T GetSource<T>() where T : IConnection
        {
            Type listType = typeof(T);
            if (listType == typeof(SomebaseWrapper))
            {
                return new SomebaseWrapper(_connection.GetSource<SomeBase>());
            }
            if (listType == typeof(ExternalBaseWrapper))
            {
                return new (ExternalBaseWrapper)(_exconnection.GetSource<T>());
            }
            throw new Exception("Not supported");
        }
```

Comment: I assume you are missing an important point that `IConnection` shouldn't be depending on 3rd party class. Instead of `string GetConnectionString()`, try changing it to `Connection GetConnection()` and now your contract has dependency on `3rd party` connection dependency

Comment: That was exactly my point: if you want both 3d party classes from one factory, that means they provide similar functionality. The idea was to refactor this functionality into `IConnection` interface without dependencies. `GetConnection` should not return 3d party `Connection`. Why do you need 3d party `Connection`? Probably to connect. So I propose to put `Connect()` method into `IConnection` and hide 3d party specifics behind your own wrapper-implementation. If two 3d party classes are so different you cannot think of an interface, than probably they don't belong into the same factory..

Answer (score -1):

You have to use reflection for this. The most convenient way if something like convenience exists at all with reflection, is to use generic types, i.e. `MakeGenericType` and cast the result appropriately. This also has the advantage that you only perform the checks once for each type.

```
public class SourceFactory {
    private class SourceGetter<T> {
        public static readonly SourceGetter<T> Instance;
        static SourceGetter() {
            Type listType = typeof(T);
            if (listType == typeof(SomeBase))
            {
                Instance = (SourceGetter<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(CollectionGetter<>).MakeGenericType(listType));
            }
            else if(listType == typeof(ExternalBase)){
                Instance = ...            }
            else {
                Instance = new SourceGetter<T>();
            }
        }
        public virtual T GetSource(SourceFactory sourceFactory) {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
    private class CollectionGetter<T> : SourceGetter<T> where T : SomeBase {
        public override T GetSource(SourceFactory sourceFactory) {
            return sourceFactory._connection.GetSource<T>();
        }

    }
    ...
    public T GetSource<T>()
    {
        return SourceGetter<T>.Instance.GetSource(this);
    }

    private Connection _connection;
    private ExternalConnection _exconnection;
}
```

*Edit:* Modified the code to make it easier to extend.

Comment: I have not down-voted, but this design would be rigid, its is binding to two different types `Connection, ExternalConnection`, now user wants to introduce 5 more similar classes, it will bloat the overall design, and it would be unmanageable

Comment: @MrinalKamboj Agreed. I changed the code to mitigate this problem but it was not the point of my answer. Anyhow, it is really sad if people downvote thoughtful answers. Please whoever downvoted the answer, please comment so I can take a note that I will never ever going to help you.